# Error when installing .deb file

Tags: debian

I'm trying to manual install firmware-atheros package in my netbook but I'm getting error messages. I downloaded the .deb file from debian site. I'm using debian jessie.

Below is the command I use to install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install ./fw-ath.deb
```

Below are the last errors being encountered.

```
E: Release 'fw-ath.deb' for 'python-gnome2....' was not found
E: Release 'fw-ath.deb' for 'libcairomm....' was not found
E: Release 'fw-ath.deb' for 'python2.7....' was not found
```

Comment: Does it work better with `sudo dpkg -i fw-ath.deb`?

Comment: I also got an error when using dpkg. It says not a debian pacjage. Im sure that file is not corrupted

Comment: What exactly did you download? Can you [edit] your question to include the link?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like an easy solution. I'd reccomend installing gdebi from the repos and then doing sudo gdebi NAME to install it. It should resolve all the deps for you. If it can't find them then find and add repos that have them.